# OAuth API for Four Square

Tags: java, oauth, foursquare

Has anyone use any good Java API for four square oauth ? I am looking for something that is thread safe ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started by using [foursquare4j](http://code.google.com/p/foursquare4j), but was unable to get it to successfully retrieve an access token, which is the final step needed before calling signing calls to the Foursquare API.
So I switched to using [signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) to get through the authentication bit and get an access token and secret, and then used foursquare4j as it encapsulates the API as a very nice object model.
I don't know if signpost or foursquare4j are inherently thread safe - you could ask that question in their forums.
Below is a flatten version of the code I am using to authentication my App.
I'm using the Play framework - authorize() receives the initial request for authentication, and oauth() is where foursquare redirects to once the user has allowed access.

```
public class Foursquare extends Controller {

    static final String FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN = "http://foursquare.com/oauth/request_token";
    static final String FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN = "http://foursquare.com/oauth/access_token";
    static final String FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_AUTHORIZE = "http://foursquare.com/oauth/authorize";
    static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "N4FKW2GFLMU1UGR3DDQYE4IGJQRGID1JFXYPJS3XFLZN3EU6";
    static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "DDGHBF25J3RJDD4N4QC2CMRF8YMA1CG94OGFRPTY4RQNLMVH";


    // Handle Request for foursquare Authorization
    public static void authorize() throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthNotAuthorizedException, OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException {

        oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN, FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_AUTHORIZE);
        oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
        String authURL;

        authURL = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,"");

        String tokenSecret = consumer.getTokenSecret();
        session.put("secret", tokenSecret);
        redirect(authURL);
    }

    // Handle call back from foursquare after user Accepts
    public static void oauth() throws IOException, OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthNotAuthorizedException, OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException {

        oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN, FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,FOURSQUARE_OAUTH_AUTHORIZE);
        oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
        String secret = session.get("secret");
        String pinCode = params.get("oauth_token");
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(pinCode, secret);
        provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, pinCode);

        // Get the access token and secret
        String token = consumer.getToken();
        String tokenSecret = consumer.getTokenSecret();

        // Set foursquare4j Credentials
        foursquare4j.type.Credentials credentials = new Credentials();
        credentials.setTokenSecret(tokenSecret);
        credentials.setAccessToken(token);

        foursquare4j.oauth.OAuthConsumer newConsumer = new OAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

        foursquare4j.oauth.FoursquareOAuthImpl fs = new FoursquareOAuthImpl(newConsumer, credentials);

        try {
            // Get last 50 checkins
            Checkins checkins = fs.history("50", "");

            render(checkins);
        } catch (FoursquareException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found some changes in the parameters of constructors of DefaultOAuthProvider and DefaultOAuthConsumer?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Andrew I am almost done setting up a module for the super cool Play Framework to talk to Foursquare through OAuth.

You can follow the progress on my blog http://geeks.aretotally.in or Github https://github.com/feliperazeek/playframework-foursquare.

Watch out because Foursquare is turning off OAuth 1 in favor of OAuth 2 very soon.